# Jekyll's life cycle

Tags: jekyll

Can somebody explain what the Jekyll's life cycle is ? I mean in what order the variables are created/collected, the urls are constructed, the pages/posts are rendered.

I hope that this will help me to understand for example why some variables can be overwritten and other can't (for example I can't set a `permalink: pretty` in the front metter of a page), why we can't set more than one layout, and so on ...

Probably the best way to understand this is to read the code, but I'm not a Ruby programmer :(

Comment: No need to read the source, they have a wiki for that. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/wiki/How-Jekyll-works

Comment: @approxiblue thanks for this very interesting link ! I was hoping for a little bit more details : how the yaml preambles are collected (are they joined and then parsed, or parsed one by one) ? when are urls created ? in what order pages/posts are generated/rendered ? ...